# How to add new key in body in the body mapping template in on AWS API gateway

Tags: aws-api-gateway, aws-step-functions

I am API on AWS API Gateway, which triggering AWS Step Function.

Following in body mapping template:

```
{"input" : "{\"httpMethod\": \"POST\",\"body\": \"$util.escapeJavaScript($util.escapeJavaScript($input.json('$')))\"}","stateMachineArn":"arn:aws:states:us-east-1:xxxxxxxx:stateMachine:TestStartStateMachineForUnmanaged-MnwLb4sqy6uq"}
```

I want to add new key in the body, i.e. `"account-type": "self account"`

How we can add this?

Comment: Do you want to add a key to get it later like a parameter in the step function?